# Spaceships, detective seeking golden gauntlet, may already have silver gauntlet

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for some help IDing a book I read once. It included space ships, and the main character was male. The point of the book was a search for a Golden gauntlet, and it also included a Silver gauntlet that I believe the main character already had. I believe the main character was also a PI or Detective or something similar. I know that's not much to go on but any thoughts on what this book might be called would be great; I've run out of search options. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not sure where you got the info that the book was a novel? You've added "novel" to the title and tags, but it doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the original post, and there are no deleted comments from the OP.

Comment: zapman2000, please don't put rants in your posts. Stack Exchange posts are community-editable by design. If you object to an edit on your post, you can always undo it by hitting "rollback" in the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/186798/revisions). I've now reverted the drastic edit and made some minor edits to improve punctuation etc. I hope this is an acceptable compromise :-) Good luck finding the book! Also, it might be worth glancing through the [checklists here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/) to see if you can remember any more details.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - What other sort of book do you think it might be?